# JavaCC and Unicode issue. Why \u696d cannot be managed in JavaCC although it belong to the range "\u4e00"-"\u9fff"

Tags: java, unicode, compiler-construction, antlr, javacc

We're trying to use JavaCC as a parser to parse source code which is in UTF-8( the language is Japanese). In JavaCC, we have a declaration like:

```
< #LETTER:
  [
   "\u0024",
   "\u0041"-"\u005a",
   "\u005f",
   "\u0061"-"\u007a",
   "\u00c0"-"\u00d6",
   "\u00d8"-"\u00f6",
   "\u00f8"-"\u00ff",
   "\u0100"-"\u1fff",
   "\u3040"-"\u318f",
   "\u3300"-"\u337f",
   "\u3400"-"\u3d2d",
   "\u4e00"-"\u9fff",
   "\uf900"-"\ufaff"
  ]
>
```

If it meets a string like "日建フェンス工業", it will fail because of 業 character. If I remove it, it works as expected. The code of 業 character is "\u696d", and as you can see in the declaration, it should belong to the range "\u4e00"-"\u9fff"

Any suggestion on this?

PS: If we rewrite this grammar using Antlr, how does it look like

Thank you so much

Comment: Post your grammar file around the `#LETTER`.

Comment: there are a lot of grammar rules around this token, which would you like to see

Comment: The token definition to be matched with  "日建フェンス工業".  `#LETTER` is only a fragment of some tokens.

Comment: @Hai Pham: Are you still trying to build a PL/1 parser? (Ours has been validated on >10,000 real programs, including preprocessor directives).

Comment: Have you tried using the DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER=true option?

Comment: what kind of partnership would you like to work on Ira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your token fragment and nothing wrong with JavaCC. The problem lies elsewhere.

Here is a JavaCC specification made by copying and pasting your problem code into JavaCC.

```
options {
  static = true;
  debug_token_manager = true ; }

PARSER_BEGIN(MyNewGrammar)
package funnyunicode;
import java.io.StringReader ;

public class MyNewGrammar
{
  public static void main(String args []) throws ParseException
  {
    MyNewGrammar parser = new MyNewGrammar(new StringReader("日建フェンス工業"));
    MyNewGrammar.go() ;
    System.out.println("OK."); } }
PARSER_END(MyNewGrammar)

TOKEN :
{
  < WORD : (<LETTER>)+ >
|
  < #LETTER:
  [
   "\u0024",
   "\u0041"-"\u005a",
   "\u005f",
   "\u0061"-"\u007a",
   "\u00c0"-"\u00d6",
   "\u00d8"-"\u00f6",
   "\u00f8"-"\u00ff",
   "\u0100"-"\u1fff",
   "\u3040"-"\u318f",
   "\u3300"-"\u337f",
   "\u3400"-"\u3d2d",
   "\u4e00"-"\u9fff",
   "\uf900"-"\ufaff"
  ] >
}

void go() :
{Token tk ; }
{
  tk=<WORD> <EOF>
}
```

And here is the output from the resulting Java program

```
Current character : \u65e5 (26085) at line 1 column 1
   Starting NFA to match one of : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u65e5 (26085) at line 1 column 1
   Currently matched the first 1 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u5efa (24314) at line 1 column 2
   Currently matched the first 2 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u30d5 (12501) at line 1 column 3
   Currently matched the first 3 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u30a7 (12455) at line 1 column 4
   Currently matched the first 4 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u30f3 (12531) at line 1 column 5
   Currently matched the first 5 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u30b9 (12473) at line 1 column 6
   Currently matched the first 6 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u5de5 (24037) at line 1 column 7
   Currently matched the first 7 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
Current character : \u696d (26989) at line 1 column 8
   Currently matched the first 8 characters as a <WORD> token.
   Possible kinds of longer matches : { <WORD> }
****** FOUND A <WORD> MATCH (\u65e5\u5efa\u30d5\u30a7\u30f3\u30b9\u5de5\u696d) ******

Returning the <EOF> token.

OK.
```

As you can see the generated tokenizer has no trouble seeing `\u696d` as a `LETTER`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this was my mistake/eclipse. I tried to clean the project then rebuilt and I no longer see this error

Answer (score 0):

In an ANTLR grammar it would like very similar. Here's a lexer fragment (from my MySQL grammar):

```
// As defined in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html.
fragment LETTER_WHEN_UNQUOTED:
    '0'..'9'
    | 'A'..'Z' // Only upper case, as we use a case insensitive parser (insensitive only for ASCII).
    | '$'
    | '_'
    | '\u0080'..'\uffff'
;
```

Note that ANTLR does not handle input beyond the BMP.